# Create List Item SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, crud

I have a SharePoint hosted app that creates a list instance. I'm trying the simple task of creating a list item but it doesn't work. No errors are displayed and I am not able to get into the success or failed methods when debugging.

```
function createListItem(appwebUrl) {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(appwebUrl);
     var oList =   clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CustomList');

     var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
     this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
     oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
     oListItem.set_item('CustomField Text', 'Hello World!');
     oListItem.update();

     clientContext.load(oListItem);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
   );
}


 function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
 }

 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
     alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I've also tried this with REST and the same thing occurs. No error, it just doesn't work. What's up with my App?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the function is getting invoked properly. Then change below

```
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
```

to

```
oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
```

Comment: Remove "this." didn't change anything. I'm invoking the method on a button click like so createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);

Comment: Have you tried adding some alert statement just to make sure how far it goes.

Comment: I can debug right up to "clientContext.executeQueryAsync". The alerts shown in the code never fire.

Comment: Remove this from the functions.. Also check if the item actually got created or not.

Comment: I removed 'this' as you can see in my above edit. The item is definitely not created